# Is it better to use Actions.sendKeys() or WebElement.sendKeys() to simulate a user typing with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

As far as I'm aware there are two ways of typing with Selenium:

```
new Actions(webDriver).sendKeys("text to send").perform();
webElement.sendKeys("text to send");
```

The `Actions` method seems like the most natural way of replicating a user typing as the keys are sent wherever the browser wants (I believe a method called sendKeysToActiveElement is being used under the covers). However, many tutorials instruct testers to use the `WebElement` method (this is in fact the only option when using SafariDriver), I assume as it is simpler.

Is the `Actions` method actually a better simulation of user interaction, or should I use the `WebElement` method for convenience?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**public Actions sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence... keys)**

Sends keys to the active element. This differs from calling WebElement.sendKeys(CharSequence...) on the active element in two ways:

1. The modifier keys included in this call are not released.
2. There is no attempt to re-focus the element - so sendKeys(Keys.TAB) for switching elements should work.

for more you can refer this link : https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#sendKeys-java.lang.CharSequence...-

Comment: Good answer, this is also the conclusion that I came to.

Comment: Glad That I could help !

Comment: What is meant by the following?
'The modifier keys included in this call are not released.'

Comment: @Afser2000 The statement means that the modifier keys (like Shift, Ctrl) pressed before executing the line still remains pressed and is not released.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answert the question directly but I would have thought using `SendKeys` in the `WebElement` class would have been better, since you already have the `WebElement` object in memory, why do you need to create an `Actions` object?

I have always used the `WebElement.SendKeys()` method and I have not found any uses to switch over to using the `Actions` class for sending over a regular string.

I would use the `Actions` class when I require more complex scenarios e.g. Need to hold down a button or drag something.

Comment: I agree jamie with you...`WebElement.SendKeys()` is perfect to use when you want to send only text.

Comment: But that involves making an assumption that the element in question would have been the one that the user would have typed in. For example, say I have a test that opens a dialog and types some text in the automatically selected text field. If I use `Actions.sendKeys()` then the text will only be typed in the field if it is selected, and hence a test can fail if it is not automatically selected. If I use `field.sendKeys()` then the text will be sent to the field even if it wasn't automatically selected and I won't notice the error.

Comment: There is no assumption. The person writing the code should know what they are attempting to do.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. If you want to recreate exactly the interactions of a user, it is better to use Actions, otherwise it is better to use `webElement.sendkeys()` because it is more practical and simple.
2. If you need to execute a complex action like drag and drop it is also better to use Actions.